# Changing HTML attributes of Elements in Mateial-UI Library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm doing a project which uses React and Material Design.
I'd really like to go with [Material UI Library](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui), but there are certain additional requirements like accessibility via aria-Attributes and heavy autocompletition on forms.

Matrial UI uses it's own components, e.g. `<TextField>`, which creates an Input field like this:

```
<div style="...">
    <div style="...">Hint Text</div>
    <input type="text" id="..." style="...">
    <div>
        <hr style="...">
        <hr style="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I for example wrap a (HTML-)Label around the `<input>` or add an aria- or name-attribute?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: I believe to do this you would have to clone the [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/src) repository and modify their existing components to add the HTML as you desire. Material-UI's components aren't made to be changeable like that. You could try [materialize](http://materializecss.com/) if you need something more customisable.

Comment: materialize sadly doesn't have the fancy Date- and Time Pickers I'll need for this :( but I'll keep an eye on it for future projects, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Material-UI does it for you.**

The library passes html props down the chain to the < input /> for you, so you just do the following:

```
<TextField label="myLabel" />
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try this and mark it as the right answer if it works! do you know if this (and maybe other "hidden features") is documented somewhere?

Comment: I also learned it from somebody else, but if you think about it, it does make sense.